# Update object in Do-function in RethinkDB

Tags: go, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-go

Example data in table *rooms*:

```
{
    "id": "8ae9865-b602-41f7-8637-9fd5517095d9",
    "members": {
        "12345": {
            "Id": 12345,
            "Name": "User1",
            "LastUpdated": timestamp
        }
    }
}
```

My query:

```
        result, err := r.DB(rethinkdbDatabase).Table("rooms").Filter(
            r.Row.Field("members").HasFields(playerIdStr)).Nth(0).Default(nil).Do(func(room r.Term) interface{} {
            return r.Branch(
                    room.Ne(nil),
                    room.Update(map[string]interface{}{
                            "LastUpdate": r.Now(),
                    }),
                    r.DB(rethinkdbDatabase).Table("rooms").Insert(map[string]interface{}{
                            "id": r.UUID(),
                            "members": map[string]interface{}{
                                    playerIdStr: map[string]interface{}{
                                            "LastUpdate": r.Now(),
                                            "Name":       request.Player.Name,
                                            "Id":         request.Player.Id,
                                    },
                            },
                    }, r.InsertOpts{
                            Durability: "hard",
                    }),
            )
    }).Run(rethinkdbClient)
```

It gives the following error:

```
gorethink: Expected type SELECTION but found DATUM:
{
    "id":   "08ae9865-b602-41f7-8637-9fd5517095d9",
    "members":      {
    "7360165":      {
    "Id":   7360165,
    "LastUpdate":   {
    "$reql_type$":  "TIME",
    "epoch_time":   1486826898.51,
    "timezone":     "+00:00"
    },
    "Name": "Player1"
    }
    }
} in:
r.Do(func(var_10 r.Term) r.Term { return r.Branch(var_10.Ne(<nil>), var_10.Update({LastUpdate=r.Now()}), r.DB("drill_dev").Table("rooms").Insert({id=r.UUID(), members={7360165={LastUpdate=r.Now(), Name="Player1", Id=7360165}}}, durability="hard")) }, r.DB("drill_dev").Table("rooms").Filter(func(var_9 r.Term) r.Term { return r.Row.Field("members").HasFields("7360165") }).Nth(0).Default(<nil>))
```

To my understanding, the issue appears to be, that the *room* variable is of type *OBJECT* which is not compatible with the update function, therefore the call room.Update({...}) does not work. How can I update the "LastUpdated" field in the nested document without having to filter the table again, using the *room* variable?

Answer (score 1):

Because the document `room` has an id, you can select the document by id (instead of filtering the whole table a second time) and update it that way.